# Amazon Marketplace API

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws, amazon-marketplace

I was expecting amazon marketplace web service to be as simple as any other web service but it is not....

There seems to be a tiny bit of information about marketplace product feeds, and could any one help me on how to start from uploading a new product(step by step-as i am new to this),and also updating the quantity or price in future onto amazon in C#.net

If anyone can give a short summary, I'd be very grateful. All I want to do is I have a web site which displays a list of products. I need to send this list onto amazon for display through one of their API using C#.net. After digging I felt like Marketplace Web Service is appropriate but I dont see any wsdl url to upload the product info.Please help.

Comment: What type of seller account do you have?

Answer (score 7):

Use the amazon C# client library here: https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/api.html/180-1400280-4320051?ie=UTF8&section=feeds&group=bde&version=latest

Answer (score 7):

The main steps for submitting an Amazon Marketplace product feed that I've used are:

- Use the SubmitFeed method to upload the feed to Amazon in CSV or XML.
- Use the GetFeedSubmissionList method to get the list of current submissions and their 'FeedProcessingStatus'.
- Continue to poll this method and the FeedProcessingStatus will change from 'SUBMITTED' to 'IN_PROGRESS' to 'DONE'.
- Use the GetFeedSubmissionResult method to get the Feed Processing Summary.

Temboo has a good library for Amazon Marketplace which actually chains these steps together, so it can be a time saver. The Temboo SDKs are available for JAVA, Python, PHP, Ruby, Node.js, Android, and iOS. You can check it out here: https://www.temboo.com/library/Library/Amazon/Marketplace/

(Full disclosure: I work at Temboo)

Comment: I still want to know is there any wsdl file for MWS?

Comment: @yuyue007 I couldn't find a WSDL, but they do have XSDs you could use to generate proxy classes -- https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=165016.  However, we've already found one bug in them (specifically, `RelatedProductID` element missing from latest amzn_envelope.xsd file) so YMMV

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to upload products to amazon.  The Marketplace web service as mentioned and the AMTU, amazon merchant transport utility.  Version 2 of AMTU is based on MWS.

Regardless of the method you choose you will still have to format feeds in XML or flat file format.  The xsd's for XML and flat file formats are documented and samples of these are available through your seller account.